# Drawing mirrored arrows in C

Tags: c

I am having trouble with drawing this shape in C using asterisk:

```
*         *
**       **
***     ***
****   ****
***** *****
****   ****
***     ***
**       **
*         *
```

I know how to make either the right or left arrow, but I don't know how to make them like this. This is the code that I have so far, which makes the left arrow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n,i,j;
    printf("N:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(j=i; j<n; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=n; i>=1; i--){
        for(j=i; j<=n; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(j=1; j<i; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: For every line, how many stars are to be displayed, and how many spaces need to be in between? It is really not a hard problem. You need to think about it a bit more.

Comment: The desired image contains an `*` everywhere `r` is closer to 4 than `c` is closer to 5, where `r` is the row number (0 to 8) and `c` is the column number (0 to 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to draw shapes in ASCII, you have to ask yourself what characters you are printing in what order. Draw it manually (with a keyboard, not on paper eh) if you have to.

In the case of your double arrows:

```
*         *
**       **
***     ***
****   ****
***** *****
****   ****
***     ***
**       **
*         *
```

The sequence here starts with star, space x9, star, `\n`, star x2, space x7, star x2, `\n`, star x3, space x5, star x3, `\n`, ...

So here's one possible solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
      putchar('*');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 9 - (i * 2); j++) {
      putchar(' ');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
      putchar('*');
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      putchar('*');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 11 - (i * 2); j++) {
      putchar(' ');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      putchar('*');
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by identifying the patterns in the figure.

```
*         *
**       **
***     ***
****   ****
***** *****
****   ****
***     ***
**       **
*         *
```

We have a number of stars, a number of spaces, then a number of stars again.

| line num | stars | spaces | stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 * | 9 ␠ | 1 * |
| 2 | 2 * | 7 ␠ | 2 * |
| 3 | 3 * | 5 ␠ | 3 * |
| 4 | 4 * | 3 ␠ | 4 * |
| 5 | 5 * | 1 ␠ | 5 * |
| 6 | 4 * | 3 ␠ | 4 * |
| 7 | 3 * | 5 ␠ | 3 * |
| 8 | 2 * | 7 ␠ | 2 * |
| 9 | 1 * | 9 ␠ | 1 * |

We could also see it as a number of stars, an amount of padding, a space, an amount of padding, then a number of stars.

| line num | stars | padding | spaces | padding | stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 * | 4 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 4 ␠ | 1 * |
| 2 | 2 * | 3 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 3 ␠ | 2 * |
| 3 | 3 * | 2 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 2 ␠ | 3 * |
| 4 | 4 * | 1 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 4 * |
| 5 | 5 * | 0 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 0 ␠ | 5 * |
| 6 | 4 * | 1 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 4 * |
| 7 | 3 * | 2 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 2 ␠ | 3 * |
| 8 | 2 * | 3 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 3 ␠ | 2 * |
| 9 | 1 * | 4 ␠ | 1 ␠ | 4 ␠ | 1 * |

For the first 5 lines, we print

1. a number of stars equal to the line number
2. a number of spaces equal to `5` minus the line number
3. a single space
4. a number of spaces equal to `5` minus the line number,
5. a number of stars equal to the line number

If `i` is the line number, this simplifies to

1. `i` stars
2. `( 5-i ) * 2 + 1` spaces
3. `i` stars

We can find a similar pattern for the last 4 lines. With this we can achieve the desired result using two loops.

1. Loop such that `i` goes from 1 to 5 inclusive,

   1. Print `i` stars.
   2. Print `( 5-i ) * 2 + 1` spaces.
   3. Print `i` stars.
   4. Print a line feed.
2. Loop such that `i` goes from 4 to 1 inclusive,

   1. Print `i` stars.
   2. Print `( 5-i ) * 2 + 1` spaces.
   3. Print `i` stars.
   4. Print a line feed.

We could even generalize this to a single loop.

1. Loop such that `j` goes from -4 to 4 inclusive,

   1. Let `i` be `5` minus the absolute value of `j`.
   2. Print `i` stars.
   3. Print `( 5-i ) * 2 + 1` spaces.
   4. Print `i` stars.
   5. Print a line feed.

Finally, it's best if we avoid using `5` and derived value all over the place.

1. Loop such that `j` goes from `-(n-1)` to `(n-1)` inclusive,

   1. Let `i` be `n` minus the absolute value of `j`.
   2. Print `i` stars.
   3. Print `( n-i ) * 2 + 1` spaces.
   4. Print `i` stars.
   5. Print a line feed.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void putcharx( char ch, size_t count ) {
   while ( count-- )
      putchar( ch );
}

int main( void ) {
   int n = 5;
   for ( int j = -(n-1); j <= (n-1); ++j ) {
      int i = n - ( j >= 0 ? j : -j );
      putcharx( '*', i );
      putcharx( ' ', ( n-i ) * 2 + 1 );
      putcharx( '*', i );
      putchar( '\n' );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G44e6fPWo) on Compiler Explorer

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pattern, we can see the asterisks are bounded by the two diagonal lines *y* = +*x* and *y* = −*x*, with the coordinate origin at the center of the pattern. In fact, there is an asterisk at each point (with integer coordinates) where |*y*| < |*x*|.

Therefore, we can produce the pattern by iterating `y` and `x` over the coordinates in the image (−4 to +4 and −5 to +5, respectively) and printing an asterisk wherever `abs(y) < abs(x)` and a space otherwise. We also print a newline character at the end of each row:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int y = -4; y <= +4; ++y, putchar('\n'))
        for (int x = -5; x <= +5; ++x)
            putchar(abs(y) < abs(x) ? '*' : ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function drawing it for any (odd) number.

```
void drawArrow(unsigned x)
{
    if(x % 2)
        for(unsigned row = 0; row < x; row++)
        {
            for(unsigned col = 0; col <= x + 1; col++)
            {
                if((row <= x / 2 || row == x / 2) && (col <= row || col > x - row)) putchar('*');
                else if((row > x / 2) && (col > row + 1 || col < x - row)) putchar('*');
                else putchar(' ');

            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
}

int main(void)
{
    drawArrow(19);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6WK55Kv1a

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough cut that uses `printf()`'s formatting facilities. It's limited to 10 max, but that's easy to extend...

```
void out( int w, char *rp, char *lp ) {
    printf( "%*.*s %*.*s\n", w, w, rp, w, w, lp );
}

void main() {
    char *s = "**********          **********";

    char *lp = s+10;
    char *rp = s+20;

    int w = 7;

    for( int i = 1; i <= w; i++ )
        out( w, lp - i, rp - w + i );
    i--;
    while( i-- )
        out( w, lp - i, rp - w + i );
}
```

If the rp & lp parameters received by `out()` are swapped, a diamond is drawn, instead.